# Rosbag package not found-fuerte

Tags: navigation, build, ros-fuerte, laser-pipeline, source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am using fuerte
I am getting the following error when i am trying to rosmake packages laser_filters,laser_assembler,costmap_2D etc. "Package rosbag was not found in pkg-config search path.Perhaps you should add the directory containing 'rosbag.pc' to PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable."
I have rosbag installed and when i checked the directory "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/pkgconfig"
rosbag.pc seems to be present there. I am confused why am still getting the error. !
Can any one please help me regarding this

Regards,
Radhika

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46652/rosbag-package-not-found-fuerte/) by [Radhika](https://answers.ros.org/users/3209/radhika/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-10-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why are you trying to rosmake the packages? Just use the debian packages:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-laser-pipeline navigation
```

I guess the problem is that you checked out the development versions of the packages which are probably already ported to Groovy (the upcoming ROS Distro). If you really need to compile the packages from source, make sure you check out the Fuerte branch.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0